# Encrypt with PHP and Decrypt with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database, encryption

What I am doing is encrypting data with PHP when inserting new customers. However later on I will need to decrypt the entire table using SQL Server commands. However I am running into a problem where I think DecryptByKey will only accept a `Varbinary`. However when I encrypt with PHP it doesn't produce a `Varbinary` variable. The two encryption algorithms should be the same.

What am I doing wrong?

PHP I use to encrypt:

```
function fnE($sV, $sS)
{
    return trim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sS, $sV,
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ),
                MCRYPT_RAND)
            )
        )
    );
}
```

This turns "James" into "/mucJj8Znec7aygh3ly2DI45bSxyv6vG4dzFz4SVVHk=" which is inserted into a table called 'customer_details' in column name 'first_name'.

Then in SQL Server I create a master key with the same password as I used in PHP.

Then I do:

```
Create Symmetric Key AdvSym
With Algorithm =AES_256
Encryption by Certificate AdvCert
GO
```

But whenever I try to decrypt it just shows NULL:

```
Select first_name,
Convert(Varchar(100), DecryptByKey(first_name)) as DecryptedName from customer_details
go
```

EDIT: It should be known that I am success in encrypting and decrypting when using ONLY SQL. However I need to be able to encrypt using PHP then decrypt using SQL.

Comment: Hey, this might not work for you, but have you considered just using an encrypted connection between the web server and the database server?  You can enforce encrypt on SQL connections.  Then just pass the firstname plain text and let the DB do both.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the same credentials when in sql and within the application.

SQL documentation states that when unallowed database users attempt to decrypt a value, even when using the correct key name and salt if used, the result will return null if the database user has view definition false for said key.

A workaround I've used, if you don't want you application user to be able to have permissions over a key, is to write the select within a user defined multiple statement table function and inside it change use the 'with execute as [allowedUserhere].'

Remember to allow your application user to "impersonate" your "key user" for this to work.